# Как изменить переменную PHP после каждой прогонки кода?

Tags: php, javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
              $('.art_container').append('<?php 
                    include('assets/php/includes/db.php');
                    $i = 0;
                    $article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` LIMIT ". $i .", 1");
                    while ($article_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article)) {
                      echo '<div class="col-xs-3 blog'. $article_array['categorie'] .'"><div class="sback" style="background-image: url('. $article_array['img'] .')"><a href="#" class="square">'. $article_array['title'] .'</a></div></div>';
                    };
                    ?>');
           }
        });
```

Как прибавить переменную $i после прогонки скрипта, суть в том что б на скроле вниз прибалялась статья, спасибо!

Comment: Не мешайте так js и php) посмотрите в сторону ajax погрузки статей..пхп код срабатывает на сервере а не в браузере...

Comment: Спасибо, просто я недавно начал учить веб разработку про ajax даже и не слышал раньше!

Comment: Незачто. Сначала разберитесь в том что начали учить. У этих двух языков координально разные назначения.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис вот-вот, надо разбираться: [не за что](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/не_за_что), [кардинально](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/кардинально).